# Rspec - undefined method 'let'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

This is my rspec file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Birds" do
  before { visit birds_path }
  it "should have the right title" do
    expect(page).to have_content("Approved Birds")
  end
  it "should contain the bird's name, genus, species" do
    let(:bird) { FactoryGirl.create(:bird) }
    expect(page).to have_content("#{bird.name}")
    expect(page).to have_content("#{bird.genus}")
    expect(page).to have_content("#{bird.species}")
  end
end
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: let(:bird) { FactoryGirl.create(:bird) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `let' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0xad87f84>
```

My Gemfile has both 'rspec-rails' and 'capybara' gems. Anyone have any idea on how to fix this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
describe "Birds" do
  let(:bird) { FactoryGirl.create(:bird) }
```

you should never have a `let` block inside of a `it` block. It should be called from within a `describe`

Comment: I would like to add, that you shouldn't use `let` in `before` blocks as well (you should use `let!` in this case). The only place for `let` blocks is within a `describe` block. 
Read more about it on https://kolosek.com/rspec-let-vs-before/

Answer (score 6):

`let` is  only defined within `describe`.  You've used it within `it`