# undefined method `let' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I'm having a 'Undefined method let' error while trying to run a minitest spec.

Here's the spec:

```
require 'test_helper'
extend Minitest::Spec::DSL

class AccountTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # test "the truth" do
  #   assert true
  # end

  let(:entity) { Entity.create }
  let(:user) { User.create(plan: 0, entity: entity) }

  test 'valid account' do
    account = Account.new(user_id: user, name: 'Нал', type: :cash, currency: 'RUB', category: :regular)
    assert account.valid?
  end

end
```

Here's the test_helper file:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'shoulda/context'
require 'shoulda/matchers'
require 'minitest/reporters'
Minitest::Reporters.use!
include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all
end
```

Here's the part of a Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem "minitest-rails"
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'minitest-reporters'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'minitest-rails-capybara'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl'
end
```

What's wrong with me? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rspec - undefined method 'let'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820224/rspec-undefined-method-let)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following require to your test helper:

```
require "minitest/rails"
```

If you add the require you don't need the `extend Minitest::Spec::DSL` in your test.

Comment: are you sure this is required now? I was able to do with just `require 'minitest/autorun'`and use describe block as answer below suggests.

Answer (score 1):

`let` is only defined within `describe`.

Try putting it inside `describe`

```
describe "let" do
  let(:entity) { Entity.create }
  let(:user) { User.create(plan: 0, entity: entity) }
```